# Series 1 watch display pops off but still works! Can I just glue it?

Tags: hardware, apple-watch

I have a series 1 watch and part of the screen just popped off and open and closes like a hinge. Display still works though. Can I just for glue it, if I only plan to use it for sleep tracking? Or is there some danger?

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend fixing the display of the Apple Watch with an adhesive. There are tons of certified tools out there that can fix your Apple Watch as if it were new. If you glue it you run the risk of damaging components or not liking the end result, and it's hard to undo it if you've used glue.

Comment: I think the question for the OP is, is their series 1 Apple Watch valuable enough to be worth fixing properly, _and if not_, would using an adhesive be better than _doing nothing at all_?

Comment: Yes exactly ☝️ That’s precisely what I’m wondering